# elm : install elm format extension

Tags: unix, command-line, environment-variables, elm

I have installed `elm-format` package (using `amp install elm-format`)  and I want to run it from the command line , example elm-format mypage.elm

In order to run it from the command line it should be available in one of the environment path let's say `usr/local/bin` **while** the elm-format directory is installed in the following path `Users/myuser/.atom/packages` and none is available in env path

what should I move to the PATH (`usr/local/bin`) , is the whole folder or an executable file

note : when i run  ls Users/myuser/.atom/packages/elm-format i get the followings :

`CHANGELOG.md README.md keymaps     menus       src
LICENSE.md  example     lib     package.json`

Answer (score 2):

I will answer my question since I have solved it.

first you have to install the elm-format binary file using your browser  form the following [URL](https://github.com/avh4/elm-format)

after installing the binary file extract it  add the path to the environment path
for windows user add `elm-format.exe` or mac user add `elm-format`

since I am a mac user I used the below command to add it :
`mv ~/Download/elm-format /usr/local/bin/elm-format`
after installing the binary now we need to install `elm-format` extention for the appropriate editor
since I am using **atom** editor  I have used the following command `apm install elm -format`

now we can used elm-format command line to format the elm page

*command line* : `elm-format pagename.elm`

Comment: the better way is to use npm as kkpoon suggested in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to npm [website](https://www.npmjs.com/package/elm-format) You could install elm-format by `npm install -g elm-format`.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone using VS Code (on a Mac / Linux system):

1) Choose Download ZIP in the 'Clone or Download' dropdown on the [elm-format Github repo](https://github.com/avh4/elm-format).

2) To move the elm-format executable to your 'PATH', open the Terminal application and enter the following command:

```
mv ~/Downloads/elm-format /usr/local/bin/elm-format
```

3) Open VS Code and install the extension `elm-format`.

4) Still in VS Code, open User Settings. (Do this by pressing `CMD` + `SHIFT` + `P` to open the available commands search bar and type `User Settings` -- press enter. Alternatively, you can use the shortcut `CMD` + `,` to open the User Settings.)

5) In the file that shows up on the right side of the editor (your personal settings overrides), add the following line:

```
 "elm-format.formatOnSave": true
```

Save.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

For Atom configures: https://atom.io/packages/language-elm for **Syntax highlighting** and **autocompletion**, for **auto format** on saving https://atom.io/packages/elm-format

For the others IDE https://guide.elm-lang.org/install.html (VScode, Atom, Sublime, Vim,...)